# Show sql records where date is in the future php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an SQL query that will show up coming coach trips on a web page.  I would like the page to drop any trips that have already happened.  here is my code so far.  but I am getting this error when I try it, The error message:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given 
in /homepages/3/d383808630/htdocs/php/checker/show.php on line 67
```

Here is the code, Please help!

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM checker WHERE date  > GETDATE()");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  echo 
  "<div class='destpic'>" . $row['id'] ."</div>" . 
 "<div class='topinfo'><p class='topinfo'><span class='topinfo'>" .
  $row['date'] . "</span><br /><span class='topinfo'>" . 
  $row['displayer'] . "</span><br /><span class='topinfo'> " . 
  $row['forum'] . "</span><br /><span class='topinfo'> ";
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `GETDATE()` is a function from SQL SERVER. Try using `CURDATE()` instead.

Comment: Absolute Legend. *FIXED*

Comment: @今 草 顿 웃 please don't forget to post an answer to the question for future users.